# How can I fetch all the user who liked an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `User` and `Community` models.

`Community` model will be liked by a user by this command

```
    if current_user.voted_up_on? @community
        current_user.dislikes @community
    else
        current_user.likes @community
    end
```

and I'm now trying to fetch all the users who liked @community. 
I'm trying to do it with this. But it won't return correct users.
How can I fix this?

```
@users =  User.where(:id => @community.likes.map(&:voter_id)).order("last_active_at DESC").limit(10)
```

I'm using the gem called 'acts_as_votable' for this
https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would return AR::Relation

```
# Note: I'm not sure that polymorphic fields are: "votable_type" and "votable_id"

class Community
  ...
  def last_liked(limit = 10)
    User.includes(:votes).where(["votes.votable_type = ? AND votes.votable_id = ?", self.class.name, self.id]).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(limit)
  end
end
```

Comment: If I'm using that only once in controller can I write like this?   `@users =  User.inlcudes(:votes).where(["votes.votable_type = ? AND votes.votable_id = ?", 'Community', @community.id]).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(10)`

Comment: I tried this. However this didn't work either:( `@users =  User.inlcudes(:votes).where('votes.votable_id' => @community.id ).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(10)`

Comment: `@users = User.inlcudes(:votes).where(:votes => {:votable_type => "Community", :votable_id => @community.id}).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(10)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`@users = @community.likes.map(&:voter)`

Comment: Thanks But it returns NoMethodError (undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x0000001a4577d8>): if I wrote like this @users =  @community.likes.map(&:voter).order("last_active_at DESC").limit(10)

Comment: Use `@community.likes.order("last_active_at DESC").limit(10).all.map(&:voter)`

Comment: thats because the `map` returns an array, not an ActiveRecord relation, so you can't do order and limit on it.

Comment: @DanielEvans Thanks but now it says this :(   last_active_at is in Users table.    `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'last_active_at' in 'order clause': SELECT  `votes`.* FROM `votes`  WHERE `votes`.`votable_id` = 17 AND `votes`.`votable_type` = 'Community' AND `votes`.`vote_flag` = 1 ORDER BY last_active_at DESC LIMIT 10):
`

Comment: To get the `order` and limit on there, you probably want to manually add a `voters` or `likers` association on the community class.